# functionality wrapped inside angular module as npm package

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to provide certain functionality for an angular app which should be pack inside npm package. **Is it good idea to wrap this functionality inside angular module?**

If it is can you provide some links or references to learn from.

Comment: depends if it will be something you will reuse later on. You can look at any angular module and see how it's done.

Comment: yes, it will be used later on. Is it normal to wrap this module functionality as npm package?

Comment: It's very normal to create an angular module. Now whether or not you upload that to the npm registry, that depends if you want to reuse it on several projects or you want to make it public